# How to help kids to hold their cards in their hands ?

Tags: kids

I'm trying to show some card games to my kids (4 and 6), but they have difficulty holding the cards in their hands. Maybe it's because their hands are too small, or not strong enough...

Does anyone have a trick to help them?

Comment: Have you considered smaller size playing cards?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Patience is the only thing I can think of, with my kids (aged 6) I started by fanning them out and place them in their hands finished, lately they collect them and take a grip and I only fan them out for them.

As an alternative just buy a couple of Playing Card Holders and worry about it later on :)
[image: Card Holder]

These should be available a little everywhere but the image is taken from: [Peta](http://www.peta-uk.com/acatalog/Playing_Card_Holder.html) (first image of them I found on google image search)

Answer (score 8):

When I was a kid, I would put my cards on a chair beside me. That way my parents couldn't see them, but I didn't have to hold them.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to Don's pretty comprehensive solution: Have you considered playing some games with the hands 'open' (the cards showing, usually inevitably spread on the table)?

Although this removes a large chunk of the strategy in most games (which may well be beyond them initially), it will give them a chance to look at their opponent's hands and anticipate their next move. Thus allowing them an easier introduction to closed-hand game strategies.

Answer (score 6):

I have the answer! You will need to purchase some Pringles, or something else that comes in plastic-lidded cylindrical cans like that.

- Take two lids and punch a hole in the center of them
- Put the lids top-to-top and use a brass brad through the hole to hold them together

Now you can put the kids' cards in them - face down and you're not even peeking!

Oh. I see that [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/311/how-to-help-kids-to-hold-theirs-cards-in-their-hands/314#314) has a picture of what I'm describing a DIY version of....

Answer (score 2):

To help my 6-year-old daughter play Uno with the family, my 10-year-old son just grabbed a chip clip that you would use to hold a bag of potato chips and flipped it upside down. He showed my daughter how to fan her cards and place them in the clip. With a little practice, she is using it to play Uno with the rest of the family. Prior to this, we had a family friend who helped her set up a cereal box in front of her cards with her cards laying face up on the table. This was doable, but she still felt like a "baby," and she felt disconnected with the cereal box in front of her face. She loves the chip clip solution!!!